# Fastest way to get a vector<cv::points2d> from a vector<cv::points2d> by a vector of indices "vector<int>" in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, optimization, computer-vision

In short, I have a `vector<cv::point>` that holds all the projected points onto the image, and I have another vector that holds the individual indices of a cluster from many clusters, I want to construct another `vector<cv::point>` using these indices to get the cluster. What is the fastest way to do it?

I tried pre-allocating the memory and just looping over the indices but I want to know if there is a more efficient way that will speed things up for me.

```
// std::vector<std::vector<int>> & indices_vec this comes from another function

for (int i = 0; i < indices_vec.size(); i++) {
    std::vector<cv::Point2d> image_points_vec(indices_vec[i].size());
    int cnt = 0;
    for (auto & idx : indices_vec[i]) {
      image_points_vec[cnt] = points[idx];
      cnt++;
    }

// Do stuff with the image_points_vec
}
```

Comment: Can every index appear exactly once in every index list? Are the index lists sorted (ascending)?  Is each index list typically sparse or dense or unknown?

Comment: what is typically bigger, the number of index-lists or the total number of points? How's their size relation approximately?

Comment: - Every index appears exactly once.

- The index list is not sorted.

- Each index list typically dense.

- The total number of points is always bigger than the number of index-lists, To clarify, There are ~5000 points and each cluster contains approximately ~150 points so ~150 indices and on average 10 index lists.

Comment: Is the ordering within an index list important? If not, sorting it could help copying the points because of caching.

Comment: You’re not going to make this code significantly faster. Sorting might speed it up a bit, but the sorting itself also takes time. Are you sure this is a bottleneck in your code? Or are you going by the old adage that “loops are slow”? You can avoid explicitly keeping a counter by `reserve`ing the memory in the vector, and `push_back` each point. But that just moves the counter to inside the vector code, it shouldn’t make much of a difference in speed.

Comment: After this step, that cluster vector will go to a cuda kernel, the time taken by the kernel is ~26 micro seconds while the cluster vectors generation takes about 1 millisecond

Answer (score -1):

I find this C++20 workaround more readable:

```
#include <ranges>
for (int i=0; auto& indice_cluster : indices_vec) {
    std::vector<cv::Point2d> image_points_vec(indice_cluster.size());
    std::ranges::copy(
        std::views::transform(
             indice_cluster,
             [&points](std::size_t j)
                      {return points[j]}),
        std::begin(image_points_vec));

// "i" was declared to be used in case needed
++i};
```

C++23 can make it even denser:

```
for (auto& indice_cluster : indices_vec){
auto image_points_vec=
     std::views::transform(
          indice_cluster,
          [&points](std::size_t j)
                   {return points[j]}) |
     std::ranges::to<std::vector>();
//Do your stuff
};
```

Comment: Note that the question was how to make it faster, not how to make it denser, more readable (I'd kinda dispute that one anyway), or write it using a more recent C++ standard. I don't see any kind of proof that what you propose actually achieves what the question asks for.

Comment: @DanMašek, There's not much room to bit the optimizer on a `for` loop over a contigeous range. Not using explicit indice, I am trying to minimize risk of iteration/indexing errors. I don't want to recommend `memcpy` or any platform-dependent behavior. I'd be glad to see your suggestions.